# Load one row per time to find where the error exist

Tags: r

I try to use this data

```
data.frame(id = c(1,2), col1 = c("text---here","text---there"))
```

in order to execute this command which makes the text of second column with separated by a specific string to be in new columns

```
df2 <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(stack(setNames(strsplit(df$col1, "---", fixed = TRUE), df$id))[2:1]))
```

However I receive this error:

```
Error in table(stack(setNames(strsplit(df$col1,  : 
  attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements
```

In my real dataset I checked that some rows run without this error. Is there any way to change this command in order to run it for every row and find through this way which row has the problematic text with some special characters which made the command not to run?

expected output

```
data.frame(id = c(1,2), text = c(1,1), here = c(1,0), there = c(0,1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can split the 'col1' with `strsplit` and use `mtabulate`

```
library(qdapTools)
cbind(df1['id'], mtabulate(strsplit(df1$col1, "---", fixed = TRUE)))
#    id here text there
#1  1    1    1     0
#2  2    0    1     1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = c(1,2), col1 = c("text---here","text---there"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `cSplit_e` from `splitstackshape`

```
splitstackshape::cSplit_e(df, 'col1', '---', type = 'character', fill = 0, drop = TRUE)

#  id col1_here col1_text col1_there
#1  1         1         1          0
#2  2         0         1          1
```